# BaseX XQuery gives error message „Context is undeclared“

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

The following xquery code runs into the error „Context is undeclared“. I am using BaseX v9.1.2.

[image]

How is it possible that this error happens there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your return statement, there is no context for the XPath to be applied. Use the `$el` variable bound in your loop:

```
return <key-val><key>{ data($el/as:SERVICE-INSTANCE-REFS/...
```

Comment: True. I've forgot about it. Thank you.